# GitHub, Git-LFS and Azure

Tags: azure, github, rstudio, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I have an existing repository on GitHub into which I need to push a file of >1.5Gb. I found `git-lfs` as a solution. But before implementing I need to clarify a few things.

1. Will the repository be still on GitHub or will I need to migrate to git-lfs?
2. How to configure `git-lfs` to store the large file of a remote server like Azure?
3. Is Azure a complete replacement of Git? If I have a repo on Azure will it show up on Git Hub?
4. Does `git-lfs` work with R-Studio?

Comment: GitHub stores LFS content in Amazon s3 buckets. GitHub will take care of that when you push the contents. You don't get to choose where the content is stored. I have no idea about R-Studio.

Comment: Azure is no replacement to git and azure won't show up in GitHub, azure is a cloud platform with many features. Azure Repos (part of Azure DevOps), can also be used to host git repositories, is stores the LFT files in Azure blob storage in the same region as your Azure DevOps organization. But there is no need to migrate to Azure Repos, Github supports Git and Git-LFS just fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this is at best a set of questions and not a single one. And it lacks focus.